# Is it possible to close a JFrame in Java with X ( red x right and up ) and don't close the whole program?

Tags: java, jframe

Is it possible to close a JFrame in Java with X ( red x right and up ) and don't close  the whole program (close only this Jframe)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean the setDefaultCloseOperation method?

Comment: Yes DeiAndrei.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following method from the JFrame class:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(int)
```

according to the documentation:

Sets the operation that will happen by default when the user initiates a  "close" on this frame

Possible values:

```
JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE — Exit the application.
JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE — Hide the frame, but keep the application running.
JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE — Dispose of the frame object, but keep the application running.
JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE — Ignore the click.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);`
and the JFrame will just dispose when pressing x, if it fit´s your conditions.

For further information you could take a look into the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)) of the JFrame